# How to replace the values of List with the Keys of a Dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a List that will look something like:

```
[0] "StudentName1, Math, History, English, Lunch"
[1] "StudentName2, History, Math, English, Lunch"
[2] "StudentName3, Math, Lunch, English, History"
[3] "StudentName4, English, History, Math, Lunch"
[4] ", English, History, Math, Lunch"
```

I want to substitute the first split of each element in the list

```
 ("StudentName1, StudentName2, StudentName3, StudentName4)
```

With the Key values I have in a Dictionary:

```
"Mike", Value
"Jamie", Value
"Chris", Value
"Mary", Value
```

So that the first line of the new List would look like

```
[0] "Mike, Math, History, English, Lunch"
```

I tried to create a new List off my existing one but I can't seem to add my Dictionary Keys in the same step.

I have tried:

```
List<string> modifiedStudentList = new List(existingList.Select(s => s.Replace(s.Split(',')[0], studentMap.Keys.ToList().ForEach(x => x));
```

But it's not actually a statement, which I understand. I am just trying to see what's the most efficient, accurate way to do this.

EDIT: I have found that sometimes my Name can be an Empty string so the Replace won't work.

Comment: A Dictionary doesn't guarantee any particular order. How are you associating keys to positions in the List?

Comment: `var result = existingList.Zip(myMap.Keys, (e, a) => e.Replace(e.Split(',')[0], a)).ToList();`

Comment: Sorry! I actually saw that one of my records has an empty string for the Student name. Is there a way to handle this without Repalce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be wary of using a Dictionary when order is important. It would be better to use an ordered list of student names like so:

```
        List<string> studentNames = new List<string>();
        studentNames.Add("Mark");
        studentNames.Add("Jamie");
        studentNames.Add("Chris");
        studentNames.Add("Mary");

        List<string> existingList = new List<string>()
        {
            "StudentName1, Math, History, English, Lunch",
            "StudentName2, History, Math, English, Lunch",
            "StudentName3, Math, Lunch, English, History",
            "StudentName4, English, History, Math, Lunch"
        };

        List<string> modifiedStudentList = existingList.Select(s => s.Replace(s.Split(',')[0], studentNames.ElementAt(existingList.IndexOf(s)))).ToList();
```

(The trick here is to replace the first element of `s` with the element from studentNames at its `s`th index, e.g. the 2nd row of the info list gets the 2nd element from studentNames)